# PB 12.5 and OrcaScript: how to use reverent PBD file in OrcaScript

Tags: powerbuilder

I am trying to create a script through ORCAScript to build PB125 application but It's throwing error like undefined data type.

Right now I am using two PBD files (`pbwsclient125.pbd`,`pbdom125.pbd`) in my workspace for reference.

All files which I am using in my target.

```
pbwsclient125.pbd
pbdom125.pbd
a1.pbl
a2.pbl
a3.pbl
```

ORCA Script:

```
start session
SET liblist "a1.pbl;a2.pbl; a3.pbl"
SET application "performed.pbl" "performrx"
BUILD library "a1.pbl" "" PBD
BUILD library "a2.pbl" "" PBD
BUILD library "a3.pbl" "" PBD
BUILD application full
BUILD executable "performmed.exe" "pbshell.ico" "performmed.pbr" "yyyyyyy"
end session
```

It's throwing error like

```
Object: u_grievance
Function: u_grievance::wf_ws_get
(0052): Error C0001: Illegal data type: soapconnection
(0087): Error C0015: Undefined variable: awdqc_conn
(0089): Error C0015: Undefined variable: awdqc_conn
(0152): Error C0001: Illegal data type: soapexception
(0154): Error C0015: Undefined variable: e11
(0154): Error C0003: Condition for if statement must be a boolean.
(0211): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0213): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0219): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0223): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0225): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0232): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0235): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0238): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0243): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0298): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0311): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0335): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0348): Error C0020: Function with no return value used in expression
(0357): Error C0015: Undefined variable: e11
This object is exist in "pbwsclient125.pbd".
```

Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to include "performed.pbl" in "SET liblist" ?. Here is the documentation: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00844.1252/html/pbug/CHDDCIEA.htm

Comment: Yes I need to do full build and exe and application object is exist in "performed.pbl". basically throwing error because the reference PBD (pbwsclient125.pbd,pbdom125.pbd) is add in script but when I tried to PBD it's giving error again. Is there any ORCA commend to add reference  PBD in ORCA script?

Comment: build executable exeName iconName pbrName pbdflags [machinecode]    [newvstylecontrols] >>>>  pbdFlags >>>>

String composed of a series of Y and N values for each library in the library list. A value of "nnyy" indicates that there are four libraries in the library list, the last two being PBDs. Objects from PBLs are copied into the executable; objects from PBDs are not copied.

Answer (score 0):

I use `build project` instead of `build application`, but I think you need to add the PBDs like `pbwsclient125.pbd` to your `set liblist` command.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have used both of PBD files  in liblist command but it's not working. it's throwing different error like.
Start Session
Set Liblist
"pbwsclient125.pbd”
“pbdom125.pbd”
“a1.pbl”
“a2.pbl”
“a3.pbl”
Orca error in 'setLibList'. Result Code -4.
Library 'pbsoapclient125.pbd' failed to open
An OpenLibrary() operation failed. It is possibly locked by another user or deleted.
Last Command Failed.
End Session

Answer (score 0):

SET liblist "a1.pbl;a2.pbl;a3.pbl;pbwsclient125.pbd;pbdom125.pbd"
BUILD executable "performmed.exe" "pbshell.ico" "performmed.pbr" "yyynn"

Comment: Thanks for reply.. It's not working throwing error like "pbwsclient125.pdb" "pbdom125.pbd" Orca error in 'setLibList'. Result Code -4. Library 'pbwsclient125.pdb' failed to open An OpenLibrary() operation failed.  It is possibly locked by another user or
deleted.